Cordova Mobile Package does not render Frontend
I'm developing a web app and is using Cordova to Package the web app to a mobile app.
The Build is working but the mobile app is not rendering the actual front end of my application.
I have tested the Cordova build, specifically the index.html file. After some checking, the mobile app works but the connection to the script is not properly rendering. After changing the content and just simply placing "hello world", the mobile app rendered the hello world. Meaning the Cordova build was not the issue, from my understanding, but instead the connection to my script.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>AOS-INV</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/src/index.jsx" type="module"></script>
    <!-- <h1>Hello World</h1> -->
  </body>
</html>


My first initial though for the issue is the cors origin issue. My web app is using cors and I set the origin to be be my localhost. I've updated my cors to this more recent code block:
app.use(cors({
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    // Allow requests with no origin (like mobile apps or curl requests)
    if (!origin) return callback(null, true);

    if (/^http:\/\/localhost(:\d+)?$/.test(origin)) {
      return callback(null, true);
    } else {
      return callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  // origin: /^http:\/\/localhost(:\d+)?$/,
  credentials: true
}))

Even with this recent changes the mobile is still not rendering the front end properly.
But the cors itself is for the request on my backend and not specifically my frontend. I don't seem to understand the issue itself why the rendering is not working properly.
I'm using android studio for just my avd and my IDE is VSCode, and is just running my emulator using my terminal. I'm new to using android studio and mobile development in general, is there a way to see logs in the mobile / emulator?
Any insights will greatly help, and if I lack any information just feel free to ask and I'll provide it as soon as I can.

The page is served via https and so you need to make https calls. From your code I see you are using http.
